# Running MariaDB server 5.5 and sharing my.cnf on multiple diskless nodes

Tags: linux, mysql, redhat, mariadb, my.cnf

I'm attempting to install MariaDB Server 5.5 in a diskless image using Redhat Enterprise 7.8.

The problem I am running into is having a single diskless image with a single `/etc/my.cnf` being deployed to all the nodes, which then are all pointed to the same data directory on the shared NFS storage.

What I would like to do is somehow have the `/etc/my.cnf` determine which node it is on and write to a different directory on the shared storage (i.e. `datadir = /sharednfs/output/node1,2,3,4/mariadb`). Is this possible?

From what I researched it looks like the only way would be to setup a separate diskless image for each node. I'm unable to find any parameters in `my.cnf` that would allow a hostname variable or something of the sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a RHEL system handy, but assuming it is pretty close to centos7.

Sure seems like you could easily handle this by overriding `mariadb.service` unit somehow.

Perhaps add a `ExecStartPre` that adds a script that will replace the my.cnf with a symlink of `/etc/my.cnf` to something like `/nfspath/$(hostname -f)_my.cnf`.

Or perhaps there is a way to just override the ExecStart. I don't think `$()` is valid here, but if it was something like this. Perhaps run it via `sh -c`?

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr --defaults-file=/nfspath/$(hostname -f)_my.cnf
```

Comment: There's `%H` or `%l` if you need that, see [systemd.unit - Specifiers manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers). Just make sure that the unit file runs after systemd-hostnamed.

Comment: Fancy, I didn't know systemd had that feature. That should make it easy. You just have to override the ExecStart

Comment: Thank you Zoredache and mforsetti for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work by creating an override file for the mariadb systemd service and adding

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/nfspath/%H_my.cnf --basedir=/usr`

Just to clarify, the --defaults-file option has to be the first argument in the line, it would not work otherwise. Thank you again for both of your inputs!